# How do I pass level 28 on Pet Rescue Saga without connecting to Facebook?

Tags: pet-rescue-saga

According to the [official Pet Rescue Saga FAQ](http://about.king.com/games/pet-rescue-saga/faq), it is possible to play all of the levels of Pet Rescue Saga without connecting to Facebook.

> **Do I need a Facebook account to play Pet Rescue Saga?**
>
> No. You can play the full game without connecting to Facebook. You can also play Pet Rescue Saga without an Internet connection.

However, after completing level 27 on the Android version, I can't seem to get to level 28 without connecting to Facebook.  Has anyone been successful getting to level 28 of Pet Rescue Saga on Android without Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I posed the question to petrescuemobile@support.king.com.  Unfortunately, the answer was not what I was looking for.

My question to Pet Rescue support:

> On the Pet Rescue Saga FAQ (
>   http://about.king.com/games/pet-rescue-saga/faq ), I see that it is
>   possible to play all levels of the game without connecting to
>   Facebook.  After level 27, however, I am being asked to connect to
>   Facebook, and cannot seem to get around it.
>
> Is it possible to play all of the levels of Pet Rescue Saga without
>   connecting to Facebook? If so, how?  If not, you should probably
>   update your FAQ because it is quite deceiving.

Scanning through the long generic reply, the following statement answers the question.

> Every few levels (starting with level 27), you have to unlock a new
>   episode, in order to continue playing. This can be done by either
>   asking 3 friends for help when connecting with Facebook or by paying
>   for the ticket.

So the FAQ statement on the Pet Rescue FAQ is a bit vague, probably on purpose.  Yes, it is possible to play the full game without connection to Facebook, however, it comes at a price.

Answer (score 0):

You have to buy a ticket. There is no other way around buying a ticket unless you have Facebook to help you along the way.